# MySQL Get Yesterday Content

Tags: mysql

I would like to have user can see their yesterday picture uploaded on profile page.

I this correct?

```
SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE userid = '$userid' AND DATE(pictureuploadeddate) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 25 HOUR) ORDER BY uploaded DESC
```

Yet still not working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: **What exactly** is not working?

Comment: @Jocelyn : my fault, ORDER BY should be pictureuploadeddate Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
DATE(pictureuploadeddate) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

to take advantage of the index,

```
pictureuploadeddate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND pictureuploadeddate < CURDATE()
```

Comment: @J W now they do more faster! Thanks expert!

Answer (score 1):

Take the following condition should be OK.

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE(pictureuploadeddate), '%m-%d-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `DATE(pictureuploadeddate)` isnt `pictureuploadeddate` a date format column?

My below solution assumed `pictureuploadeddate' to be a date type column. You can simply do a comparison like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE userid = '$userid' AND pictureuploadeddate = ADDDATE(CURDATE(), -1) ORDER BY uploaded DESC
```

`ADDDATE(CURDATE(), -1)` returns yesterday's date by subtracting 1 day from today.

Comment: Maybe it's a datetime column.

Comment: @somnath I have that. Thanks!